# Remove specific *directories* from JaCoCo report

Tags: gradle, jacoco

I’m using JaCoCo Gradle plugin in my project.
Just as an example of the question, most of my code is under package `com.me.mysoftware`.

I’m using code generator that generate classes under `build/generated/java/....../com/me/software/MyGeneratedClass.java`

I would like that all of the classes under this generated directory will be excluded from JaCoCo report, but not the entire package (what’s under src/main/...)

How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

add `excludes = [ com.me.software.MyGeneratedClass ]`

see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html#default_values_of_the_jacoco_task_extension for more help

Comment: This is not helpful as I have hundreds of such generated class. This is the reason I'm looking to exclude the entire directory.